# Is there any way to send a startup key-stroke to an application running in wine?

Tags: linux, wine

Long story short, I'm trying to access a special window in Synthesia which is only displayed if you execute the application using *Shift+Click*. The problem is that I can't figure out how to reproduce this on Linux, while running the app under wine. I thought it may be a command line thing, but I couldn't find a command which does it either.

That leaves me with this, is it even possible? If so, how?

Comment: Try to disable compiz: In System > Preferences > Appearance, select None in the visual effects tab.

Comment: Done, I don't see how this helps though.

Comment: Explorer doesn't give Shift any special treatment while executing a file. It simply runs the executable as a command, otherwise how consoles and other applications can execute it? The application can't know whether you've pressed the Shift key or not. It can only do that after it has started

Comment: Exactly that, so there must be some way to emulate that on Wine, no? A simple Shift+Click on any DE doesn't work out here.

Comment: As @phuclv says, the Shift key isn't special to how the application is started, but is special _to the application once it has started_... i.e: part of the application's startup code will look at the state of the Shift key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method that can be followed is to run `Explorer.exe` under wine, then perform the Shift+Click operation. Unlike the above method, it does not rely on a specific setting to be changed or a script

Answer (score 0):

This program uses `GetKeyState` API to detect shift key as follows:

```
.text:0040D575                 call    ds:GetKeyState
.text:0040D57B                 mov     ecx, 8000h
.text:0040D580                 test    cx, ax
.text:0040D583                 jnz     loc_40E21F   ; jumps to special config dialog show
```

1. Generate bash script in `Synthesia` directory with favorite name (mine: `runme`) and fill with following lines:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   wine Synthesia.exe
   ```
2. Change its attribute to runable with `chmod +x rumne` and ensure you can click and run **instantly** bash scripts. I mean run bash scripts without asking dialog! [use this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/305776/635458)
3. HOLD <kbd>Shift</kbd> KEY and click/double click to run `runme`. the programs runs normaly! now close it but DO NOT RELASE <kbd>Shift</kbd> KEY. Do again and click/double click to run `runme` to show special config dialog.

   [image: show me!]

Comment: Instead of #2, couldn't you press and hold shift when clicking the "_Run_" button?

Comment: Bonus points for a wrapper script that does a binary patch and accepts a flag to show the normal / config window.

Comment: I tested clicking run button in ask dialog while holding shift but did not work! I can do binary patch but question was how to send startup key stroke in wine not how to run this app in config mode. if you need let me know.

Comment: It doesn't seem to let me run the script while holding down shift. I'm running KDE.

Comment: I've found a different way to run it, I simply called Explorer.exe under wine, then shift + click from there.

Comment: @Frontear: This is worth an answer, not a comment.